# Is it possible to show the number of changes since the last save in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there any normal mode option I can use to see not just if a file has been changed but how many edits there have been since the last save?

Also, is it possible to display this information in the status bar?

Comment: What should count as an "edit"?

Comment: Anything that would cause a :q to baulk without a :w beforehand

Comment: Alternatively, anything that can be undone with a u in normal mode

Comment: Vim doesn't have that out of the box but you can script it yourself `:h undo.txt`. Hint: remember the change number when saving and compare it with the current number.

Comment: You could code up some logic using `save_last` and `seq_cur` from the `undotree()` function